# Не подключается inputmask

Tags: jquery, inputmask

Попробовал подключить маску для телефона

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.phone.extensions.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#phone').mask("+9-(999)-999-99-99");  //static mask
});
</script>
```

Пишет $(...).mask is not a function. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

используйте вот эту функцию $('').inputmask('..')

Answer (score 0):

Верно подметил пользователь ***Ярослав***, почему у вас `.mask("...")`?
На [странице](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#static-masks) плагина, где идет пример простой маски(static mask), код: `.inputmask("...")`.

Рабочий пример(с jQuery):

```js
$('#phone').inputmask("+9-(999)-999-99-99");  //static mask
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>


<form action="#">
  <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" required pattern="^\+\d[-]\(\d{3}\)[-]\d{3}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}$">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> Я подключил jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js

Бонусом, добавил верный ***pattern*** для данной маски.